# sort a data frame based on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I execute the following code:

```
df<-data.frame(word=c("play","win","offer","http"),frequency=c(321,355,123,564),type=c("nonspam","nonspam","spam","spam"))

df=arrange(df,desc(frequency),desc(type))

df=df[order(df[,2],df[,3]),]
```

and the result is:

```
   word frequency type
4 offer       123    spam
3  play       321    nonspam
2   win       355    nonspam
1  http       564    spam
```

but I want to sort the data frame with respect to frequency **and** type such as:

```
word frequency type
    1  http      564    spam
    4  offer     123    spam
    2  win       355    nonspam
    3  play      321    nonspam
```

Comment: Just reverse the order - `arrange(df, desc(type), desc(frequency))`

Comment: sorry I had spam and nonspam which are strings @thelatemail

Comment: `df[order(df$type, df$frequency, decreasing = TRUE),]`

Answer (score 8):

**To sort in ascending order:**

Use dplyr like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% arrange(type, frequency, word)
```

Just arrange the variables in the order you would like to sort.

**To sort in descending order:**

Just use a negative sign in front of the variable you want to sort in reverse order. Like this.

```
df %>% arrange(-type, frequency, word)
```

**Working with text...**

If you want to try sorting text in reverse order using the method above, you may get an error. To arrange categorical variables, wrap the variable around desc(), as such:

```
df %>% arrange(desc(word))
```